# How do you create dynamic objects with dynamic keys and types in TypeScript?

Tags: json, typescript, dynamic, enums, interface

so I am doing a project where the 'admin' will create a form and the users will submit it.

I am using firebase as a back-end database and I would like to save this 'schema' to the database, the front-end form would be populated through this schema and users be able to submit their form using this.

**For example,**

Admin can create forms such as:

```
Form1: {
   name: "string", // something like this - Option 1
   numberOfBooks: { // or something like this - option 2
     type: "number",
   }
   colorType: { // With option 2, we can do something like this
    type: "dropdown",
    enums: ["Green", "Red", "Blue"]
  }
}
```

or a totally different form such as :

```
Form2: {
   shirtSize: "number",
   serialNumber: "number",
   serialValue: "checkbox"
}
```

**This "schema json" will be saved in the Firestore.**

When users tries to submit it, these types will be fetched from the Firestore, and will be populated onto the front-end ui.

Then, users will be able to submit the form such as:

```
userSubmittedForm1: { // which extends Form1:
   name: "Anthony",
   numberOfBooks: 5,
   colorType: "Green",
}

userSubmittedForm2: { // which extends Form2
   shirtSize: 5,
   serialNumber: 144,
   serialValue: "Value123",
}
```

I have been searching for answers for many days but couldn't achieve it. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I don't quite see how TypeScript helps you with this; if things are saved to a database and loaded later, where is the TypeScript compiler going to intervene?  If you knew all the types at the type you write your code you could make something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGnoVm) which validates types of submitted data.  But once things get so  "dynamic" that you can only know what's going on at runtime and not before, the compiler can't do much.  Perhaps you're asking for runtime validation?  But that wouldn't have much to do with TS as opposed to JS.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks. Its just that the project has been going on for some time with typescript based and the client suddenly wanted this feature implemented. Do you think it would be a good idea to, just for this part, use JS and do some runtime validation like how you would normally do in JavaScript? But overall, I see what you mean. I guess that, with needing runtime validation, TypeScript wont help much. Thank you very much!